# Android studio New project issues

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a new project in Android Studio but I'm not getting the expected screen.All the basic guides I've seen online have the pop-up screen as:

[image: What I'm expecting]

Yet I get this screen:

[image: What I get]

I have no idea what is going on I followed the download process normally.I don't know exactly why I don't get the normal new project pop up screen and activity templates. 
I have the 3.0 version of project SDK  1.8(1)(java version "1.80_112-release").
Thank you, if you need more information I'll edit my post.

Comment: have you tried-> file>new>new project...

Comment: Yes, the second picture is the result of that.

Comment: restart android studio and click the cancel button then you could see a option create new project just try it

Comment: I hit file invalid Caches/Restart,it restarted and  I went to file->New->Project not new project.I still get the same issue..

Comment: it seems like something went wrong while installing the Android studio can you reinstall it

Comment: What os are you working from is it by any chance 32-bit Windows ?

Comment: I'm working on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: click on gradle and proceed